# How do I push a local repository to GitHub, when I get an error saying the repository doesn't exist (it does exist)

Tags: git, github

There is probably a super simple solution, but I'm new to Git and I'm stuck on this:

I've created a GitHub account, and a repository called `Sales`. Locally, I've ran

```
git init

git add . 

git commit -m "Adding files to git for the first time"
```

`git status` returns:

```
$ git status
On branch master
nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

Then I go ahead and try to push to GitHub

```
git remote add origin https://github.com/username/Sales
```

Which returns:

> fatal: remote origin already exists.

As I would expect, because I already created it.

But then if I run:

```
git push -u origin master
```

It returns:

> remote: Repository not found.
>   fatal: repository 'https://github.com/username/Sales.git/' not found

I really have no idea what to do to fix this. One potential source of this issue, is that I earlier tried logging into a personal GitHub account, and the shell prompted me to log into that account the first time. When I changed to a newly created work account, I was never prompted to re-log-in. Do I need to force this somehow?

I changed from my personal GitHub Account to my work account using (with `username` being my work account user name):

```
git remote set-url origin https://github.com/username/Sales
```

Comment: Be aware that GitHub identifies who you are by different means, depending on whether you contact GitHub via ssh, or via https. So the URL you use for `git push` matters first. If the URL is `ssh://git@github.com/...` or `git@github:...`, you'll get ssh based authentication, which you can test with `ssh -T` or `ssh -Tv` as described at https://help.github.com/articles/testing-your-ssh-connection/

Comment: If you use https, things are more complicated, because now it's OS-dependent first, then Git-credential-helper-dependent second. There are more help pages, with OS-specific descriptions of how to set up and test each of the various credential helpers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to make sure of several things.

1. Make sure the repository exists.
2. Make sure you have added a remote for your repository. `git remote add origin repository_url`
3. Make sure you have copied your public SSH key in your [github settings](https://help.github.com/articles/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/)

Comment: I created a new SSH key and that fixed the problem.

Comment: I don't know that this solved the `HTTPS` problem, but `git push` runs, which is good enough for now.

Comment: Did you cloned your repository using https? You can check that by runing `git remote get-url origin`

Comment: Running that command just returns the SSH version `git@github.com:username/Sales.git`

Comment: That's why you weren't able to push in the first place, the thing here is that you created your remote using the SSH version of the repository, if you'd created your remote with the HTTPS version your SSH keys wouldn't been necessary

Answer (score 1):

Try to remove your remote then add it again, copying the link from github:
`git remote rm origin`
`git remote add origin your_url_copied_from_github`

Comment: When I run those two commands, they both succeed, and `git remote add` doesn't show the "remote origin already exists." error. However, `git push -u origin master` still fails with the same error

Comment: what is the result of `git pull` ?

Answer (score 0):

One potential reason might be that the repository isn't created on GitHub - make a repo called Sales in GitHub and push there

Answer (score 0):

you need to add an origin to your local repo.
use this:

```
git remote add origin <remote repository URL>
```